# Remove Legend In R

Tags: r, plot, legend

How I can remove the legend in a plot in R? I tried legend<-FALSE, doesn't work.
Also, is there a better way to set the position of the legend? For example, is there 
a way I can pick the location with my cursor? And I am not talking about ggplot or any fancy add-ons, just regular R plotting.

Comment: I used legend() to create my legend.

Comment: Once a plot is created, you can add to the plot, but nothing can be removed. You need to redraw the plot without the legend.

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes?

Comment: I'm guessing because there are multiple questions in this question (the position question shouldn't be included and having to manually set the legend location via mouse every time you run your script would be horrible) and you didn't give an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order:

- This is related to what people tried to explain to you yesterday:  Think of a *script* as primary means of creating your R session.  In ESS, you get the script as a by-product; in RStudio you can also work with commands first and then pass those to your session.  Lastly, no you can't remove a legend *which has already been added to a plot*, but you can hopefully re-create your graph using the saved commands.
- Yes, since Duncan Murdoch added support for 'topleft' etc you can use logical commands:

> ```
> plot(1:10)                    # simple plot
> legend("bottomright", "foo")  # 'foo' in bottom-right corner
> ```

- Yes, if you use the output of `locator()` as input for the `legend()` command.

Comment: Nor irrelevant at all!  Re-run your plot-creating commands but this time *without* the call to `legend()` -- voila.  And for that you need easy access to commands to create objects, plots, ... --- and hence the recommendation for a file-based workflow as detailed eg in the ESS docs. This has served me well for over a decade.  As for `locator()`, examine its examples first. It's quirky.

Comment: @GTyler once you plotted something it stays there. The only way to change something in the graph that's been plotted is to erase the whole thing and plot it again modifying what you want first. That's what @Dirk said in the first bullet point. Use `legend(locator(), "foo") to use locator inside the legend. HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which plotting function is producing the legend. (Most plotting function do not plot legends by default.)

There is a `locator` function.