# How to remove legend from path.plot() in R?

Tags: r

Is there anyway to remove legend from path.plot()?

The following is how to use `path.plot()`

```
path.plot(synth.res = NA,
dataprep.res = NA,
tr.intake = NA,
Ylab = c("Y Axis"),
Xlab = c("Time"),
Ylim = NA,
Legend=c("Treated","Synthetic"),
Legend.position=c("topright"),
Main = NA,
Z.plot = FALSE)
```

I tried `Legend.position=c("none")`, but it did not work.
I also tried to add a separate code such as `legend("none", legend=c("Treated", "Synthetic"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)` but still legend will not go away.

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365464/remove-legend-in-r>